# How to quickly select and replace any content in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

[image: This is the example in this image]

How to select this last 3 characters from all the rows and replace them quickly?

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> controls in SSMS.

Navigate to end of the word, Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>ALT</kbd> and using <kbd>KeyDown</kbd> key to select the numbers of rows going to affect then press <kbd><-</kbd> (KeyLeft) key  **three** times to select the last 3 characters from all the selected rows and simply type your expected characters there.
It will delete the previous 3 characters and replace the newly typed characters.

The trick is explained in these pages [1](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/ssms-alt-shift-trick/), [2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2786/column-and-block-text-selection-using-sql-server-management-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET CustomerName = mid(CustomerName, 1, LEN(CustomerName)-2)
;
```

But I'm not sure if that is the right solution for your problem.
Please provide more information.